# How can I handle UpdateView on same page

Tags: django

I am new to django , I want to make updateview shows the edit form in same page rather than opening a new page

```
class PostUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
  model = Post
  fields = ['title', 'slug', 'content', 'category', 'post_image']
  template_name = 'update.html'

  def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
      data = super(PostUpdateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
      data['update_form'] = data.get('form')
      return data

  def form_valid(self, form):
      form.instance.author = self.request.user
      return super().form_valid(form)

  def test_func(self):
      post = self.get_object()

      if self.request.user == post.author:
          return True
      else:
          return False
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CBV(class based views) to do that
and also it's easier to update from UpdateForm page.
so keep learning